# Convert function from Javascript to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, regex, preg-replace, slug

I've this javascript function that convert any string into *the perfect slug* (in my opinion).

```
function slugGenerator(str) {
  str = str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
  str = str.toLowerCase();

  var from = "àáäâèéëêìíïîòóöôùúüûñç·/_,:;";
  var to   = "aaaaeeeeiiiioooouuuunc------";
  for (var i=0, l=from.length ; i<l ; i++) {
    str = str.replace(new RegExp(from.charAt(i), 'g'), to.charAt(i));
  }
  str = str.replace(/[^a-z0-9 -]/g, '').replace(/\s+/g, '_').replace(/-+/g, '-'); 
  return str;
}
```

I need to convert it to PHP, I've tried and the result is:

```
function slugGenerator($str) {
  $str = preg_replace('/^\s+|\s+$/g', '', $str);
  $str = strtolower($str);

  $from = "àáäâèéëêìíïîòóöôùúüûñç·/_,:;";
  $to   = "aaaaeeeeiiiioooouuuunc------";

  for ($i = 0, $l = strlen($from); $i<$l ; $i++) {
    $str = str.replace(new RegExp(from.charAt(i), 'g'), to.charAt(i));
  }

  $str = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9 -]/g', '', $str)
  $str = preg_replace('/\s+/g', '_', $str)

  $str = preg_replace('/-+/g', '-', $str); 
  return $str;
}
```

I've problems with this for loop:

```
for ($i = 0, $l = strlen($from); $i<$l ; $i++) {

  // This string
  $str = str.replace(new RegExp(from.charAt(i), 'g'), to.charAt(i));
}
```

I've not idea on how convert it to PHP, someone could try to convert it?

**SOLUTION:**
Add the [strtr_unicode](https://github.com/qeremy/unicode-tools.php/blob/master/unicode-tools.php#L223) function and use this script:

```
function slugGenerator($str) {

    $str = preg_replace('/^\s+|\s+$/', '', $str);
    $str = strtolower($str);

    $from = "àáäâèéëêìíïîòóöôùúüûñç·/_,:;";
    $to   = "aaaaeeeeiiiioooouuuunc------";
    $str = strtr_unicode($str, $from, $to);

    $str = preg_replace(
      array("~[^a-z0-9 -]~i", "~\s+~", "~-+~"),
      array("", "_", "-"),
      $str
    );

    return $str;
}
```

Comment: Am I missing something here? Why are you creating a regular expression when all you do is replacing an exact character? `str.replace( from[i], to[i] )` should be sufficient no?

Comment: Just use PHP's `str_replace()`, no need for regexps here. It will accept array as an input, `explode()` your `$from` and pass it to `str_replace()`.

Comment: @kjetilh No, because without regex and global flag it will replace only first occurrence of the character. And using [] to fetch characters from string will not work in older browsers because this is not standard in Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `strtr` and `str_split` won't work for you cos your code contains unicode chars. There are some useful stuff if you like to use.

`str_split_unicode`: https://github.com/qeremy/unicode-tools.php/blob/master/unicode-tools.php#L145
`strtr_unicode`: https://github.com/qeremy/unicode-tools.php/blob/master/unicode-tools.php#L223

Test:

```
echo strtr_unicode("Hëëëy, hôw ärê yôü!", $from, $to);
// outs: Heeey- how are you!
```

After that, you can use arrays as param for `preg_replace`;

```
$from = "àáäâèéëêìíïîòóöôùúüûñç·/_,:;";
$to   = "aaaaeeeeiiiioooouuuunc------";
$str = strtr_unicode("Hëëëy, hôw ärê yôü!", $from, $to);
echo $str ."\n";
// according to this line: 
// str = str.replace(/[^a-z0-9 -]/g, '').replace(/\s+/g, '_').replace(/-+/g, '-');
$str = preg_replace(
    array("~[^a-z0-9 -]~i", "~\s+~", "~-+~"),
    array("-", "_", "-"),
    $str
);
echo $str;
```

Outs;

```
Heeey- how are you!
Heeey-_how_are_you-
```

Comment: Thank you, strtr_unicode works.

Answer (score 0):

this code should work:

```
$str = preg_replace('/'.$from[$i].'/', $to[$i], $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

The PHP function str_replace can take array arguments. So if you convert `$from` and `$to` to arrays, you would be able to use:

```
$str = str_replace($from, $to, $str);
```

To replace all occurences of `$from` with the respective item in `$to` inside of `$str`, instead of the for-loop.

To convert `$from` and `$to` to arrays quickly you could use `str_split`:

```
$from = str_split($from); // meaning your original string from the question
// same for $to
```

Comment: I get this error: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /var/www/slug.php on line 15 Now I'll add the code edited with your advice.

Comment: `strtr` is recommended over `str_replace` for this so you don't get chained replacements.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `for` loop.  [`strtr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) was basically made for what you're trying to do:

```
$str = strtr($str, $from, $to);
```